# Cloudflare CNAME goes to defaultwebpage cgi

Tags: dns, ip, cloudflare, cname

I have `www.domain1.com` working fine using cloudflare's DNS and hosted on Softlayer. I added another domain (`www.domain2.com`) to cloudflare and created a CNAME record to point from `www.domain2.com` to `www.domain1.com`. The problem is when I try to access to `www.domain2.com` on any browser it goest straight to the `defaultwebpage.cgi` page instead of going to `www.domain1.com`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the virtual host of www.domain2.com on www.domain1.com web server, since there is no virtual host entry for domain2.com it falls back to the default web server entry.

Setting up virtual host varies based on the web server type you using.